# Alsamixer 200% without VLC

Tags: linux, audio, vlc-media-player

When I change VLC Player's volume to 200%, it appears to make everything else 200% volume after closing it. Once I open Alsamixer it still says 200%. However, if I try changing the volume at all, whether up or down, it automatically jumps to 100% and everything becomes drastically quieter.

Being that this shows that my speakers are not working at their full capacity, how can I change the volume to 200% and use the full capacity of my speakers without VLC Player?

I'm using KDE on Fedora. At one point, I was told to change my asound.conf file to have

```
pcm.!default{
    type plug
    slave.pcm "softvol"
}

pcm.softvol{
    type softvol
    slave{
        pcm "dmix"
    }
    control{
        name "Pre-Amp"
        card 0
    }
    min_dB -5.0
    max_dB 20.0
    resolution 6
}
```

which did not work. I rebooted, I shutdown and turned my computer back on, etc. Alsamixer and KMix refused to acknowledge a "Pre-Amp."

Any other suggestions for making my volume higher?